# WizardNewFileCreationPage specify folders

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, wizard

I use a WizardNewFileCreationPage to give a user the option to create a new file the project workspace.

However I want the user to create the file only in certain folders, for example in `project/data` not in `project/data/trash` folder.

How do I specify this criteria?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class which extends `WizardNewFileCreationPage` and override the `validatePage` method:

```java
@Override
protected boolean validatePage()
{
    boolean valid = super.validatePage();
    if (!valid)
      return false;

    IPath containerPath = getContainerFullPath();
    String fileName = getFileName();

    valid = ... check containerPath and fileName meet your criteria

    if (!valid)
     {
       setErrorMessage("your error message"); 
     }

    return valid;
}
```